# Side-by-side in bar plot with two y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to put bars side-by-side instead of superposed in a bar plot with two y axis in ggplot2. I know if there is only one y axis and colors were given by a factor, I could use position_dodge, but I am not able to use it with two y axis.

Here are my data:

```
structure(list(date = structure(1:3, .Label = c("2018-07-12", 
"2018-09-09", "2019-08-01"), class = "factor"), Maturity = c(0.35, 
0.02, NA), daphnia = c(0.0249, 0.0256, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))
```

Here is my graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
pa2 <- ggplot(data = mergedaph1, aes(x = date)) +
geom_bar(aes(y = Maturity), stat = 'identity', fill = "grey61", width = 0.80)+
geom_bar(aes(y = daphnia*5), stat = 'identity', color = "black", width = 0.50)+
scale_y_continuous("Maturity rate", sec.axis = sec_axis(~./1, name = "Abundance (ind/L)",
labels = function(b) { paste0(round(b / 5, 2), "")})) +
geom_vline(xintercept = (12 * (c(31, 365) / 365) + 0.5), lty = 2, size = .8)+
xlab("Date")+
theme_bw()+
theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
plot.background = element_blank(),
axis.text=element_text(size=15),
axis.title=element_text(size=17),
axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "grey55", size = 15), 
axis.title.y.left = element_text(color = "grey55", size = 17),
axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "black", size = 15), 
axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "black", size = 17)
)
pa2
```

I am also oppen to any other suggestions to make the graph more easy to read.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can see this as an option. It is a way to hack the plot using data twice and a dummy variable in order to use `position_dodge()`. You clone your data, add a category and can have the plot. Despite it works you have to adjust axis labels because they will move. I will leave the code here if maybe you find another way to explode it:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
mergedaph1 <- structure(list(date = structure(1:3, .Label = c("2018-07-12", 
"2018-09-09", "2019-08-01"), class = "factor"), Maturity = c(0.35, 
0.02, NA), daphnia = c(0.0249, 0.0256, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

How data must be hacked:

```
#Scale factor
scalef <- max(mergedaph1$Maturity,na.rm=T)/max(mergedaph1$daphnia)
#Data 1
s1 <- mergedaph1
s1$Maturity <- NA
dat1 <- rbind(mergedaph1,s1)
dat1$Cat <- c(rep('c1',3),rep('c2',3))
#Data 2
s2 <- mergedaph1
s2$daphnia <- NA
dat2 <- rbind(mergedaph1,s2)
dat2$Cat <- c(rep('c1',3),rep('c2',3))
```

And the code for plot:

```
#Plot
ggplot(data = dat1, aes(x = date,fill=Cat)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = Maturity), stat = 'identity',
           width = 0.80,position = position_dodge(1.9),show.legend = F)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('grey61','grey61'))+
  geom_bar(data=dat2,aes(y = daphnia*scalef,fill=Cat), stat = 'identity',
           width = 0.50,position = position_dodge(1.9),fill='black')+
  scale_y_continuous("Maturity rate",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./scalef, name = "Abundance (ind/L)")) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = (12 * (c(31, 365) / 365) + 0.5), lty = 2, size = .8)+
  xlab("Date")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=1),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        plot.background = element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_text(size=17),
        axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "grey55", size = 15), 
        axis.title.y.left = element_text(color = "grey55", size = 17),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "black", size = 15), 
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "black", size = 17)
  )
```

Output:

[image]

As final values are zero and `NA` they are not displayed.